# Printing a line dynamically in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I'm trying to print a line in python 3 that will change as the program goes on. For example, if I try:

```
import time
for i in range(0,10):
    print('Loading' + '.'*i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

I get:

```
Loading.
Loading..
Loading...
```

and so on. Can I make it that the previous line changes and gets another '.' added to it instead of printing a new one? Of course, I could do:

```
import time, os
for i in range(0,10):
    os.system('cls')
    print('Loading' + '.'*i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

but that causes problems of its own. I know this question has been asked before, but all the answers given to it for some reason don't work. Doing something like:

```
import time
for i in range(0,10):
    print('Loading' + '.'*i, end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

doesn't change anything, and replacing "\r" with " " just makes python not print anything for a while and then print out the whole row. What am I doing terribly wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time
print('Loading', end='.')
for i in range(0,10):
    print('', end=".")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

see [explanation of end syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) and [working example](https://repl.it/B4m4/1).

Comment: Doing `print('.', end='')` is more intuitive imo, just omitting the newline.

Comment: @Felk you're probably right about that.

Comment: That just doesn't print out anything for about 5 seconds, then I get 'Loading...........' in one print...

Comment: That's really weird.  Does the second link in the answer (which goes to a runnable example) work for you?  If it does, but it doesn't work in your interpreter, are you absolutely sure you're using python3?  (Might also be a system clock or speed issue.)

Comment: The second link won't open: 'Secure connection to server failed.'. Not sure what the problem is there. I noticed that all the answers work for most people, but not for me - maybe some strange python glitch...? BTW I am using python 3.4

Comment: On the second link, try the version w/o HTTPS, http://repl.it/B4m4/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a carriage return `\r` to rewrite the current line like this:

```
import time
for i in range(50):
    print("Loading" + "."*i, end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: I already tried that - gives the same output as the code in the question...

Comment: what kind of console are you outputting to?

Comment: I'm using WinPython, outputing to the standard console.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ANSI clear screen escape character as

```
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

Comment: I just get massive amounts of '[2J's

Comment: It works for me with OSX and python3. Should also work with linux

Comment: I'm using windows 7...